# Onclick not working when I click the button

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Reloading the page makes the function work but not when I click the button.

```
    <button onclick="randomPass()">Generate passwords</button>
```

```
function randomPass() {
    let password = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        password += generatePass()
    }
    return password
    console.log(password)
}

const pass1 = randomPass()

firstPass.textContent = pass1
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't work"_ ? 
It lgtm. If you could update your question to be an interactive, runnable code snippet, that may help both you and us answer the question.

Comment: You won't see the console because it is after the return. And in the generate function, you aren't adding the password to any text box or anywhere on the screen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but not when I click the button

Because the function doesn't really *do anything* when you click the button.  The function returns a value, but the button has no way of knowing what you want done with that value.

Here you use the returned value:

```
const pass1 = randomPass()

firstPass.textContent = pass1
```

Here (in the button click) you don't:

```
randomPass()
```

If the intent is for this to all happen on a click event, put all of the logic that you want to happen into the function:

```
function randomPass() {
    let password = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        password += generatePass()
    }
    console.log(password)
    firstPass.textContent = password
}
```

Then whether you execute it on a click event or on the page load, it's the same operation:

```
randomPass()
```